# Android Layout Rotation Issues

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having some issues with rotation on a game I'm creating. If the GameActivity is launched in portrait mode everything is fine. GameActivity also works fine if the activity is launched in landscape mode, and it uses the layout_weight property to scale the imageviews so they aren't squished, so it looks like: [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/krmeq0l9m2khyds/Screenshot_2014-02-03-16-05-53.png). My problem comes when I launch the activity from portrait mode and rotate mid-game, in which case it looks like: [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3isnwprmak9q9q2/screenshot.png). I was under the impression that if I created a 'layout-land' directory in the /res folder that android would automatically select the correct layout for the orientation but it appears that this doesn't detect changes once the activity is currently running...

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I wasn't really sure what I should include in this post to help diagnose the problem so if you need anything I'm happy to post a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you put configChanges="orientation" in your manifest? This tells Android that you're going to handle rotation changes yourself, so it won't use the layout from the landscape directory if started in portrait - because the activity doesn't get restarted.

Comment: Yep I did and now I feel silly. Thanks for the help & quick response!